# What is the best solutions for Speech To Text?

Tags: speech-to-text

I want to build a web site. Everyone can run it from any browser. it have a function to Speech to text. Are there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solution to this if you search in google.

[PHP SPEECH TO TEXT](https://github.com/rogerthomas84/php-speech-to-text)

This is a PHP script that uses Google Speech To Text API

You could definitely impliment this in your project.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it's work great. and  had try at here https://github.com/gillesdemey/google-speech-v2 . It work for me. but could i use this for JavaScript ? Just post data in to Google Speech API.